# How to place a UNION record into a specific query row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

Is it possible to get this structure back in a MySQL query?

```
+---------+------------+--------+
|  NAME   |    DATE    | TOTAL  |
+---------+------------+--------+
| BOB     | 2014-10-09 | 100.00 |
| ROY     | 2014-10-09 | 200.00 |
| JOY     | 2014-10-09 | 150.00 |
| TOTAL   | 3          |        |
| JIM     | 2014-10-10 | 100.00 |
| LIN     | 2014-10-10 | 300.00 |
| TOTAL   | 2          |        |
|         | TOTAL      | 850.00 |
+---------+------------+--------+
```

Right now I have a query that looks like this:

```
(SELECT r.id AS ID, CONCAT(g.fname,' ',g.lname) AS Name, r.arrival AS Arrival, 
    r.departure AS Departure, DATEDIFF(r.departure, r.arrival) AS Days,
    u.unit_nickname AS Unit, r.total_price
    FROM reservations r, guests g, units u 
    WHERE g.id=r.guest  AND r.unit = u.id AND r.deleted_at IS NULL
    HAVING r.arrival BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-30'
    ORDER BY r.arrival)
UNION 
(Select "TOTALS", "", count(arrival), "", "", "",SUM(total_price) 
FROM reservations)
```

Obviously the columns are different but the gist is the same. After each day I want to display a count of reservations on that day. Is this possible in MySQL?

Right now I just get that one last record of "TOTALS" and the total reservations overall along with the total money (I want to keep that record).

Comment: SQL is not the correct tool for this task. Not to say the result set is confusing: neither `2` nor `TOTAL` look like a date.

Comment: Have a look at [`GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks, but is it possible? I don't want to spend a lot of time trying to do something that can't be done.

Comment: Getting sub-totals and totals is doable and relatively easy. You want to mix `SUM` and `COUNT`.  That is also doable but not exactly in the format you want.